# Spring method security does not work for me

Tags: spring

i am new to spring security.

i try to use spring security in my application. the basic spring security functionality works fine.

but when i try to secure methods to allow only for specific role, it does not secured and that method can work for every role.

here i given my code snippet. may i know where i did mistake.

library that i used for this application are

```
01.aopalliance-1.0.jar
02.jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar
03.jstl-1.2.jar
04.logback-classic-0.9.29.jar
05.logback-core-0.9.29.jar
06.mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar
07.org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.0.RC1.jar
08.org.springframework.transaction-3.1.0.RC1.jar
09.slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
10.spring-aop-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
11.spring-asm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
12.spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
13.spring-context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
14.spring-context-support-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
15.spring-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
16.spring-expression-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
17.spring-security-config-3.1.0.RC3.jar
18.spring-security-core-3.1.0.RC3.jar
19.spring-security-crypto-3.1.0.RC3.jar
20.spring-security-taglibs-3.1.0.RC3.jar
21.spring-security-web-3.1.0.RC3.jar
22.spring-web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
23.spring-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/security-app-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/application-data-source.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!--
      - Provides core MVC application controller. See bank-servlet.xml.
     -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd"
       xmlns:ns1="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">

    <ns1:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/pages/result/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" >
          <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
              org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
            </value>
          </property>
    </bean>

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->

    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

    <bean name="/action.htm" id="action" class="com.spt3.controller.ActionController">
        <property name="methodNameResolver">
            <ref bean="paramResolver"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="paramResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.ParameterMethodNameResolver">
        <property name="paramName">
            <value>action</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">


</beans>
```

security-app-context.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

    <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/pages/accessDenied.jsp">
            <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/**.htm" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/pages/*" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/user/*" access="isAuthenticated()"/>            
            <intercept-url pattern="/md/*" access="hasRole('MD')"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasAnyRole('Administrator','MD')"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/manager/*" access="hasAnyRole('Manager','MD')"/>
            <form-login login-page="/pages/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/pages/loginfailed.jsp"/>
            <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp"/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="com.spt3.encoder.MyPasswordEncoder"/>

    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

                   users-by-username-query="
                      select username,password, enabled
                      from users where username=?"

                   authorities-by-username-query="
                      select u.username, ur.authority from users u, user_roles ur where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username =?  "
        />
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

application-data-source.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="dataSource"    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app" />
        <property name="username" value="uname" />
        <property name="password" value="pword" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

ActionController.java

```
package com.spt3.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;
import com.spt3.infc.ActionInterface;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;

public class ActionController extends MultiActionController implements ActionInterface {

    public ActionController(){
    }

    public ModelAndView getResult(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception{
        System.out.println(" - - - - - getResult() - - - - - ");
        try{
            this.getPersonalInformation("MD");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(" Exception : "+e);
        }
        return new ModelAndView("result");
    }

    public void getPersonalInformation(String role){
        System.out.println(" "+role+"'s-Personal Information.");
    }
}
```

ActionInterface.java

```
package com.spt3.infc;

import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
public interface ActionInterface {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('MD')") // Secured method only for role MD
    public void getPersonalInformation(String role);
}
```

When accessing getResult() method from url (
http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/action.htm?action=getResult) secured method can be invoked.

My **Expected Result** should be

- getPersonalInformation() method can access only for user role MD

Now **Actual Result** is

- getPersonalInformation() method is invoking every user roles.

**After using beans - Edited (1) Here**

Same problem has been occurred when using bean injection.

Here i changed the files with the code snippet.

ActionController.java is like

```
package com.spt3.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;
import com.spt3.infc.ActionInterface;

public class ActionController extends MultiActionController {

    private ActionInterface actionInterface;

    public ActionController(){
    }

    public ActionController(ActionInterface actionInterface){
        this.actionInterface=actionInterface;
    }

    public ModelAndView getResult(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception{
        System.out.println(" - - - - - getResult() - - - - - ");
        try{
            actionInterface.getPersonalInformation("MD");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(" Exception : "+e);
        }
        return new ModelAndView("result");
    }

}
```

ActionInterface.java

```
package com.spt3.infc;

public interface ActionInterface {

    public void getPersonalInformation(String role);
}
```

bean class called ActionBean.java

```
package com.spt3.bean;


import com.spt3.infc.ActionInterface;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;

public class ActionBean implements ActionInterface{

    @Secured("MD")
    public void getPersonalInformation(String role){
        System.out.println(" "+role+"'s-Personal Information.");
    }

}
```

i used constructor injection to inject the object.

```
<bean id="actionBean" class="com.spt3.bean.ActionBean"/> <!-- Bean class -->
<bean name="/action.htm" id="action" class="com.spt3.controller.ActionController">
        <property name="methodNameResolver">
            <ref bean="paramResolver"/>
        </property>
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="actionBean"/> <!-- Injecting object to controller -->
    </bean>
```

Where i did mistake. please give me the solution.

**The problem is solved.**

These are the steps i followed.

1. Configure bean in appropriate xml file
2. I used bean injection.
3. i used @PreAuthorize annotation.

Finally the classes are looks like the following snippet when the program is successfully ran.

ActionBean is a separate class i created and i implemented ActionInterface.java class and implemented the method getPersonalInformation() method.

ActionInterface.java looks like this

```
package com.spt3.infc;

public interface ActionInterface {

    public void getPersonalInformation(String role);
}
```

and ActionBean.java looks like this

```
package com.spt3.bean;


import com.spt3.infc.ActionInterface;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;

public class ActionBean implements ActionInterface{

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('MD')")
    public void getPersonalInformation(String role){
        System.out.println(" "+role+"'s-Personal Information.");
    }

}
```

ActionController.java is look like this

```
package com.spt3.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;
import com.spt3.infc.ActionInterface;

public class ActionController extends MultiActionController {

    private ActionInterface actionInterface;

    public ActionController(){
    }

    public ActionController(ActionInterface actionInterface){
        this.actionInterface=actionInterface;
    }

    public ModelAndView getResult(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception{
        System.out.println(" - - - - - getResult() - - - - - ");
        try{
            actionInterface.getPersonalInformation("MD");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(" Exception : "+e);
        }
        return new ModelAndView("result");
    }

}
```

Good luck... 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring security works by using proxies around the spring beans, which intercept the calls to methods of the beans, and throw an exception if the user doesn't have the appropriate role. But your controller doesn't call any spring bean method. It does call an instance method : `this.getPersonalInformation()`.

When doing this, you're not calling another Spring bean method, so Spring can't intercept the call, and thus can't verify that the user has the appropriate roles.

Put the `getPersonalInformation` method in another Spring bean, inject this bean in your controller, and all should be fine.

Side note : why not simply using the `@Secured("MD")` annotation for such a case? And why not put the annotation on the getResult method directly?

Comment: @JB_Nizet the problem is solved now. Actually we should need bean configuration to secure the methods. i changed @Secured("MD") to @PreAuthrize("hasRole('MD')"). after the changes it works fine and the method is secured. it's giving exception when other role's try to accessing the method... thanks a lot, sir.